# Android google map marker to enable all custom infowindow to be shown

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have my following codes as below where I am putting 2 markers just for testing purpose into my codes. The problem all works fine and the markers appear the issue now is now to customised further so that the I can control to show all info window or close all info window.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String s = result.trim();


            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "restult is"+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String  stringSucess = "";
            //markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            int height = 50;
            int width = 40;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.basgray);
            Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);

            Marker mk = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("-34"),Double.parseDouble("151")))
                    .title("First")
                    .snippet("")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            mk.showInfoWindow();

            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker))).showInfoWindow();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));



            markers.put(mk.getId(), "RED");

            Marker mk2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("-10"),Double.parseDouble("151")))
                    .title("Second")
                    .snippet("")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
            mk2.showInfoWindow();
            //setListAdapter(adapter);
            markers.put(mk2.getId(), "Green");
        }
```

In my another function I already set for custom info window as below. Here I have already set that the info window will be customised according to another class as declared below.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new BalloonAdapter(getLayoutInflater(null)));
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

    }
```

Here is my customised function to controlled the color and icon for my info window.

```
 private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

            private View view;

            public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
                //view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                //        null);
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                if (marker != null
                        && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                    marker.hideInfoWindow();
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
                //MapActivityFragment1.this.marker = marker;
                view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                        null);
                String url = null;

                if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                    if ( markers.get(marker.getId()) != null &&
                            markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                        url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                    }
                }


                final String title = marker.getTitle();
                final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
                if (title != null) {
                    titleUi.setText(title);
                } else {
                    titleUi.setText("");
                }

                final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
                final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                if (snippet != null) {
                    snippetUi.setText(snippet);
                } else {
                    snippetUi.setText("");
                }

                return view;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you save the instances of the markers created? Probably in a list and call a function to show info windows on the markers (marker.showInfoWindow()) and the reverse for hiding them.

Code Snippet: Create a global variable to save the list of markers.

```
ArrayList<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now when you create a marker as per your code, add them to the list.

```
Marker mk = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("-34"),Double.parseDouble("151")))
                .title("First")
                .snippet("")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
markersList.add(mk);
```

Now a simple function will do

```
private void showOrHideInfoWindows(boolean shouldShow){
    for(Marker marker:markersList){
        if(shouldShow)
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        else
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
    }
}
```

A good way to use info window is (in map fragment)

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindow(view, this));
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
```

And the custom class is like

```
public class CustomInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

View infoWindow;
IMapDelegate mapDelegate;

public CustomInfoWindow(View view, IMapDelegate mapDelegate) {
    infoWindow = view;
    this.mapDelegate = mapDelegate;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    displayView(marker);
    mapDelegate.onInfoWindowShown(infoWindow);
    return infoWindow;
}

private void displayView(final Marker marker) {
    ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.markerTextView)).setText(marker.getTitle());
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: any idea how to save them I am very new actually hardly managed to get this customised codes working now struggling with next task. Any codes snippet on how to achieve you idea please?

Comment: infact I am saving the id of the marker into hashtable can I utilise that? But where to call this show and off info window?

Comment: marker's id can be utilized again, only when we click on the same marker icon. We get a callback to the onMarkerClick with the current marker. We can check its id against the ids saved in our hasmap.

Comment: where and when should I call this function? IS it at the end of the onPostExecute and must it be part of asyntask class?

Comment: what do you mean by the markers id can be utilised again you mean it wont be unique for each markers?

Comment: another thing I am confuse in the custom View getInfoContents( why I set marker.showInfoWindow(); does not show all the infowindow? Actually when will this function  View getInfoContents( will get called?

Comment: markers id will be random number auto generated, every time its instance is created. Its better to relate it with any pojo object id(if you have any) then it will be same always.

Comment: I think that is find cause I am running an interval and will clear the markers anyway and build new ones. What do you mean by pojo object? So in my timer script I call clear the array list and hasttable too.  Can I keep more information in the array list which I have collected from my json ?

Comment: getInfoWindow() method should always return null(so that the default info window is not shown but your custom window will be laid).
getInfoContents() will be called when a marker is clicked or marker.showInfoWindow() method is deliberately called. It will display the marker with the title and snippet of the marker based on the custom view rendered. But it should return the rendered view. Also you should not call marker.showInfoWindow() method here. It should be called in the MapFragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136131/discussion-between-user5313398-and-vansi).

Comment: I saw in my customised codes the getInfoWindow() is the one returning the view but getInfoContents()  is the one returning null?

Comment: I first tried you method showOrHideInfoWindows is not working either it just show the last infowindow still?

Comment: I just saw your new codes. Actually why I need this custom window is that based on the hash value I will want the infor window balloon to have either green or red outline can you new function help on this?

Comment: I have put this  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        View view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindow(view, this)); is this correct?

Comment: Your new codes have issue cant resolve on this IMapDelegate? I have google on this ?